# Sql Server one-to-many relationship in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How I can create one-to-many relationship in same table?(MSSQL)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? For example, are you asking how you would represent such a relationship, or how you would enforce data integrity once such a relationship had been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add relationships with the primary key and foreign key in the same table as per any other relationship.

The following example would show you how to add a relationship between the (pk_col) PK and (fk_col) FK in the same table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.some_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_some_table_some_table FOREIGN KEY
    (
        fk_col
    ) REFERENCES dbo.some_table
    (
        pk_col
    )
```

Comment: You mentioned `pk_col` is the PK and `fk_col` is the FK. Your answer then should have been: `ADD CONSTRAINT fk_name FOREIGN KEY (fk_col) REFERENCES some_table (pk_col)`

Comment: @von v. - Indeed, I made a mistake when replacing my column names with pk_col and fk_col.  I'll edit the original to correct.  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Just like you would across two tables: create a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
create table tab1
(
  id int,
  id1 int,
  primary key (id)
)

alter table tab1
    add constraint fk_tab1 foreign key ( id1 )
    references tab1 ( id )
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a second table which keeps a set of the Id's of each two elements related in the table.